# Is this proof about Jordan algebra's correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, nonassociative-algebras, jordan-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital commutative non-associative alternative algebra.

Let $J$ be a unital Jordan algebra.
Notice Jordan algebra's are commutative and non-associative by definition.

Conjecture :

The set of $A$ algebra's and of $J$ algebra's are identical.

Is that statement true ?

I propose the following proof :

Let $x,y$ be elements.

Alternative means ( in the context of commutative multiplication )

$$ x(xy) = x^2 y $$

The jordan identity means

$$ x(x^2 y) = x^2 (x y) $$

So we are left with proving those conditions are equivalent.

Start with the first one and transform it into the second :

$$ x(x y) =  (x^2) y$$

multiply both sides by $x$ on the left

$$ x^2(x y) = x(x^2 y)$$
done

In the other direction ( changing the second one in the first one )

$$x^2(xy) = x(x^2 y)  $$

divide both sides by $x$ on the left

$$  x^{-1} x^2 (xy) = x^{-1} x (x^2 y) $$

simplify

$$ x(xy) = x^2 y $$

QED

Is this proof correct ?

Comment: You can't take inverses in an Jordan algebra can you?

Comment: why not Alex ??

Comment: You can't just assume inverses exist without providing a reason. And you won't be able to supply a valid reason in this case, because in fact many elements (arguably, *most* elements) of Jordan algebras do *not* have inverses. Indeed, most elements are zero divisors, and zero divisors cannot have inverses. Take $n\times n$ self-adjoint matrices with the Jordan product $a\bullet b:=(ab+ba)/2$, for example: if we take two orthogonal projections $a$ and $b$ onto orthogonal nontrivial subspaces, then $a\bullet b=0$.

Comment: Ok but if we interpret $x^{-1} x$ as a cancellation of multiplying by $x$ or use the general cancellation property ( $a*c = a*b $ implies that $c = b$ for nonzero $a$ ) perpaps that will work ?
I assume the cancellation property holds for powers of the same number $x$ if $x^n$ is power associative and the algebra is commutative.

Comment: @mick *I assume the cancellation property holds for powers of the same number  if $^$ is power associative and the algebra is commutative.* Ok well then you should add that to your assumptions. It is clearly not true in general.

Comment: Note that $xy$ and $y$ are not powers of $x$, so it's unclear what "cancellation property for powers of $x$" is supposed to mean or how it's supposed to apply. Also $x^2(xy)$ is short for $(xx)(xy)$ which is not written in the form $x(\cdots)$ so the cancellation can't apply to it...

Comment: As mentioned before, you don't know that $x^{-1}$ exists and even if it exists the expression $x^{-1} x^2 (xy)$ is not well-defined because your algebra is not associative. The 'correct' expression ought to be  $x^{-1}(x^2 (xy))$ and this way you can't do the 'cancellation'. I hope to be right on this example: Consider the commutative $\mathbb{Z}_2-$algebra $A$ with basis $\{1_A,x,y\}$ and products $xy=y,x^2=y^2=0$. Since $a\in A\implies a^2=0$ it is a Jordan Algebra, however $x(xy)=y\neq 0=(xx)y$.

Comment: I see. Maybe if I add the conditions powerassociative or not nilpotent ?

Answer (score 1):

You've correctly showed that a commutative alternative algebra is a Jordan algebra. Your proof of the converse is invalid though, and indeed there are Jordan algebras which are not alternative.

Here is on example: the **spin factor** $J=\mathbb{R}\oplus\mathbb{R}^n$. We think of its elements as formal sums of scalars and vectors from $\mathbb{R}^n$. The multiplication of a scalar with a scalar and of a scalar of a vector are what you think they'd be, and the product of two vectors is their inner product (thus, vector x vector = scalar).

Explicitly, $(a+\mathbf{x})(b+\mathbf{y})=ab+a\mathbf{y}+b\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{xy}=(ab+\langle\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\rangle)+(a\mathbf{y}+b\mathbf{x})$.

**Exercise**. Show the spin factor $J$ is a non-alternative Jordan algebra (for $n>1$).

Comment: Could you explain a bit more plz ?  My math and physics skills are not so good yet

Comment: @mick Do you just need help with the exercise I gave, or is there something else in my answer you'd like clarified?

Comment: Is this still a distributive algebra ? Is it nilpotent ? powerassociative ? Im not good with vectors. Also I do not know what spin factor means if that even matters.

Comment: @mick Yes, it satisfies the distributive property. Good exercise to show this! Pick elements $u=a+{\bf x}$, $v=b+{\bf y}$, $w=c+{\bf z}$ then show $(u+v)w=uw+vw$. It is indeed power associative too. The powers of $a+{\bf x}$ should be contained in the subalgebra generated by $1$ and $\bf x$, which is their span (because their span is closed under multiplication, and is a unital associative subalgebra). It is not nilpotent - after all, it contains $\Bbb R$ as a subalgebra. You can check $(a+{\bf x})u=0$ implies $u$ is a scalar multiple of $a-{\bf x}$. "Spin factor" is just the algebra's name.

Comment: I found spin factor but it mentioned dot product and jordan product instead of inner product. This confuses me. Is that the same spin factor algebra ? They said :The spin factor S = S1,n of pairs x = (x0, x) ∈ R × R^n
equipped with the
Jordan product x • y = (x0y0 + x · y, x0y + y0x), where · denotes the usual
dot product on R
n
. The trace form in this case is Tr(x) = x0.Also Does this product not reduce the dimension?
I know the dot product by
X·Y=|X||Y| cos(theta), but that is in just 2 dimensions.
Also I was thinking in terms of a cayley table for the basis elements products.

Comment: The dot product is a particular inner product. Yes, both me and whatever source you're taking from are talking about the same thing called the spin factor. The "Jordan product" refers to the multiplication operation defined on the spin factor algebra, which I gave a formula for. I am not sure what you mean by the dot product reduce the dimension. The dot product of two vectors is a scalar, and the scalars form a 1D space while the vectors form an nD space within the Jordan algebra (which itself is n+1 dimensional), if that's what you're talking about.

Comment: Barely related but perhaps you could answer this question or tell me how to improve the question ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4054523/sqrt-hypercomplex